# Paste named range from Excel to Powerpoint into named shape - VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, shapes, vba

I want to build a macro that connects our Excel-Data-Sheet with our Reporting-Powerpoint-Presentation.
So I have this named Range ("A") selected and copied.
Then I want to paste the data into a shape in Powerpoint which has the same name as my Range ("A").

```
Sub SyncWithPPT()

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape

Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
pptApp.Visible = msoTrue
Set pptPres = pptApp.presentations.Open("workingPath")

ActiveWorkbook.Names("A").RefersToRange.Select
Selection.Copy
Set pptShape = pptPres.Slides("anySlide").Shapes("A")
pptShape.Table.cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paste 'Here it won't paste correctly

End Sub
```

Everything works just fine, except the pasting. When I paste the selection everything is pasted into cell(1, 1).
But I want to copy each cell into a different cell. Like it does when you paste with STRG + V.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I lost the images by deleting my old university dropbox account. I removed the links from the question, I think it is still quite clear what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (Office 2007)...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim ppt, sld

    'presentation is already open...
    Set ppt = GetObject(, "powerpoint.application")
    Set sld = ppt.activepresentation.slides(1)

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2").Copy

    sld.Shapes(1).Table.Cell(1, 1).Select
    ppt.ActiveWindow.View.Paste

    Set sld = Nothing
    Set ppt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'this is how to extract each cell information
'assuming that ppt communication is already done.

Dim n As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ultimaFila As Long    

j = 1 'columna
ultimaFila = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For n = 1 To ultimaFila

   pptShape.Table.cell(n, j).Value = Application.Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, j).Value        


Next n

End Sub
```